# Compilation error in C strings

Tags: c

I am trying to make a string

```
#define TEST_RESULT "&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:upnp=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/\" xmlns:dlna=\"urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/\" xmlns:pv=\"http://www.pv.com/pvns/\" xmlns=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/\"&gt;&lt;container id=\"1\" parentID=\\"0\" childCount=\"0\" restricted=\"1\" &gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;VaibhavVideos&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.container&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;/container&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;"
```

I am facing the following compilation error

```
error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
error: stray ‘\’ in program
```

Can anybody point me the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This part

```
...parentID=\\"0\"...
```

should be

```
...parentID=\\\"0\"...
```

A single backslash should be written as `\\` and quote is `\"`, so you need `\\\"` in order to get `\"`

Or if you intended it to be just `"` then use

```
...parentID=\"0\"...
```

***Unrelated bonus:*** C++0x has [raw string literals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2053.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra backslash here:

```
id=\"1\" parentID=\\"0\"
                  ^
```

It should read:

```
id=\"1\" parentID=\"0\"
```